# jsp doesn't resolve fmt:formatDate when it inside spring form:input

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, spring-form

I had following code on my jsp:

```
<input id="startDate" name="startDate" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" type='date' value="${campaign.beginDate}" />" />
```

now I replace it like this:

```
<form:input path="startDate" id="startDate" name="startDate" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern='dd/MM/yyyy' type='date' value='${campaign.beginDate}' />"/>
```

and now it renders like this:

```
<input id="startDate" name="startDate" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern='dd/MM/yyyy' type='date' value='' />">
```

Thus fmt:format doesn't resolve.
How to fix described problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
<form:input path="startDate" id="startDate" name="startDate" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern='dd/MM/yyyy' type='date' value='${campaign.beginDate}' />"/>
```

With these two lines:

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern='dd/MM/yyyy' type='date' value='${campaign.beginDate}' var="formattedDate"/>
<form:input path="startDate" id="startDate" name="startDate" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" value="${formattedDate}"/>
```

The first line places the result into a var called "formattedDate".   The second line feeds the contents of that var into the value parameter.